# Why is the 'triggering element' in $form_state is the last button on the form?

Tags: ajax, forms, drupal, drupal-7

I have mymodule_field_widget_form(), that creates an auto complete text field, and 3 buttons for a custom field. On 2 buttons I'm using ajax callback functions that invoke custom ajax commands. When function execution enters the callback function of either buttons, the $form_state['triggering_element'] is always the same, the last button (form element...?) in the form that was created by the hook above. I would like to get the element that actually triggered the callback. It is possible, the this custom field is added to a content type more than once, and that is why it is important. The custom ajax command creates a jQuery ui dialog with an iframe or plain html content in it, depending on several factors, so I thought it is not necessary to re-render the whole form in which the button was triggered. Actually there is no re-rendering anywhere, maybe that is the problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Set the `#default_value` as Spudley recommended and set the `#name` attribute to something unique (use the `$delta` parameter).

Comment: In my case, setting `#name` was enough.

Answer (score 7):

> When function execution enters the callback function of either buttons, the $form_state['triggering_element'] is always the same, the last button

This is unfortunately how Drupal's form API works. If you have several submit buttons on a form, you sometimes can't tell which one was clicked.

Firstly, see [this answer on Drupal.org](http://drupal.org/node/274983) which I think might help you:

Look in your form setup code. Where you're defining the various buttons, change `'#value'` into `'#default_value'`. This will allow Drupal to recognise that the field value (ie the form submit value) can change, and therefore it won't be fixed to the value of the last button, regardless of which one was clicked.

If that doesn't help, here are a few other solutions that might help:

1. Look directly at PHP's `$_POST` array to find out which button was clicked. This works, but goes against "The Drupal Way". The whole point of Drupal's form API is to hide the raw PHP functionality from you. But at times like this it may be useful to take a peep at it.
2. Put the buttons into separate forms. This obviously would only work if you don't need any of the other fields to be submitted at the same time.
3. Create a hidden field on your form, and use Javascript to populate it with the name of the clicked button, immediately prior to submitting the form.

Hope that helps.

Comment: This partially solved the problem and gave me some ideas, thank you! After some debugging I found out tha the _form_builder_handle_input_element() function checks all input elements, and resets the triggering element over and over again, possibly because it couldn't differentiate between them (name, value). Thank you for your help!

The reason why I would not like to do js population of hidden fields is because I think it conflicts with the purpose of the Drupal Ajax API.

Comment: This is one hell of an answer! I can confirm the `#default_value` solution works!

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I'm developing a custom FAPI element type that is a row of textfields, but multivalued, allowing for a grid of textfields.  Try as i might, when I used my element in a form, the remove and add buttons were inconsistently having the triggering_element as the wrong button, Adding #name, #id, #default_value properties did not work. I was able to look at the $_POST in my button submit and ajax callbacks and now it works like a charm....

Comment: It took me all weekend to figure it all out, here's a gist of what I had to do to make this custom element to overcome this triggering element not being right: https://gist.github.com/jackrabbithanna/71e407d5ffb089b4a07778b47a5629b8